# how to activate root user

Tags: users, root

I'd prefer to use root user as my default user instead of writing sudo command to get temporary root access.
is the root user disabled by default ?
how can i start using root user?
what are the costs/benefits of this?

ps: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm completely new in Linux world.

Thanks,

Comment: Also, note that you can instead run `sudo su` to be in a root shell without enabling the root account login.

Comment: try this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/503583/i-dont-know-what-does-sudo-su-bash-mean/503634#503634) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/341980/running-a-program-as-another-user-without-typing-a-password/502222#502222)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **don't do that**.

If you want to run several commands as root, you can use `sudo su -` to get a root shell. This is useful if you're doing system maintenance, I personally do this when administering servers.

Other than that, it's a good habit to use `sudo` if and *only if* it's really necessary. This is both for security reasons and you're less likely to mess up your system.

If you find it annoying that you have to type your password too often, you could do a couple of things:

### Extend the timeout for `sudo`

Edit `/etc/sudoers` (always use this command, never edit it any other way!):

```
sudo visudo
```

Find the line similar to this one:

```
Defaults        env_reset
```

Change it like so:

```
Defaults        env_reset,timestamp_timeout=30
```

This will make `sudo` ask for your password only if you haven't used `sudo` for 30 minutes.

### Tell `sudo` not to ask password for specific commands

On one of my systems I use `mount` very often and it usually requires root permissions. For convenience, I've set up `sudo` so it doesn't require password for the `mount` command if you're in the "wheel" group. To achieve this, add a line as such to `/etc/sudoers`, again, using `sudo visudo`:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount
```

Change `/usr/bin/mount` to whatever command you wish.

If you really, *really*, **really** want to use root as your normal user, and you [understand the risks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root), use [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login). But again, you could also do it *right*.

Comment: Thanks, how can I find out which group i'm in?

Comment: Use the `groups` command. Note that in Ubuntu you are in a group that has the same name as your username by default.